# Pointer to array of base class, populate with derived class

Tags: c++, arrays, inheritance, pointers, derived-class

If I have a base class, with only virtual methods and 2 derived classes from
the base class, with those virtual methods implemented.

How do I:

```
 // causes C2259
 BaseClass* base = new BaseClass[2];

 BaseClass[0] = new FirstDerivedClass;
 BaseClass[1] = new SecondDerivedClass;
```

or:

```
// causes "base is being used without being initialized"
BaseClass* base;
// causes CC59 again
BaseClass* base = new BaseClass;

base[0] = FirstDerivedClass();
base[1] = SecondDerivedClass();
```

(or something similar)

...so that I can access the `BaseClass`s methods through the `DerivedClass`,
but by pointer and the pointer is an array of `DerivedClass`s?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Your array is of the wrong type: it stores `BaseClass` object *instances* instead of *pointers* to them. Since `BaseClass` seems to be abstract, the compiler complains that it cannot default-construct instances to fill your array.

Even if `BaseClass` were not abstract, using arrays polymorphically is a [big no-no](https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/cplusplus/CTR56-CPP.+Do+not+use+pointer+arithmetic+on+polymorphic+objects) in C++ so you should do things differently in any case.

Fix this by changing the code to:

```
BaseClass** base = new BaseClass*[2];

base[0] = new FirstDerivedClass;
base[1] = new SecondDerivedClass;
```

That said, most of the time it is preferable to use `std::vector` instead of plain arrays and smart pointers (such as `std::shared_ptr`) instead of dumb pointers. Using these tools instead of manually writing code will take care of a host of issues transparently at an extremely small runtime cost.

Comment: The problem, which is called "object slicing", is not specific to arrays -- it happens any time you assign a derived class to a base class *by value*. E.g. `BaseClass b; b = FirstDerivedClass();` is compilable C++ that nevertheless breaks silently (at best you might get a compiler warning).

Comment: Link seems to be moved.

Comment: @Jon You sir, just saved my day. I had declared an array of objects of an inherited class (with virtual functions) and expected it to work. In your answer, however, what does `BaseClass[0] = new FirstDerivedClass;` do? Did you mean `base[0] = new FirstDerivedClass;`?

Comment: Ya I haven't tried this yet, but it seems like is should be base[0]= not BaseClass[0] = . It's array of objects not an array of classes.

Comment: @user3015682 right, fixed. Not sure why it took all of us many years to spot!

Answer (score 6):

It is C++ use `std::vector` instead of simple array:

```
std::vector<BaseClass*> base;
base.push_back(new FirstDerivedClass());
base.push_back(new SecondDerivedClass());
```

As `Kerrek SB` noticed safest method is to use `std::unique_ptr`:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseClass> > base;
base.push_back( std_unique_ptr<BaseClass>(new FirstDerivedClass()) );
base.push_back( std_unique_ptr<BaseClass>(new SecondDerivedClass()) );
```

Comment: What for? Speed? Reliability?

Comment: What about: BaseClass* Base[2];Base[0] = new FirstDerivedClass;
 Base[1] = new SecondDerivedClass;

Comment: Using a vector is a good idea, but that's not the problem with the current code.

Comment: Even betterer is a `std::vector<std::unique_ptr<BaseClass>>`.

Comment: The crucial point here is to avoid object slicing by using *pointers to* `BaseClass` instead of `BaseClass` objects. Please emphasise that.

Answer (score 2):

If your BaseClass contains pure virtual methods, this will fail to compile :

```
BaseClass* base = new BaseClass[2];
```

If it doesn't, you are going to get memory leak.

In c++, this is done by using std::vector or std::array, with some kind of smart pointer. For example :

```
std::vector< std::shared_ptr< BaseClass > > arr( 2 );
arr[0].reset( new FirstDerivedClass() );
arr[1].reset( new SecondDerivedClass() );
```

Comment: An even more important problem with the OP's code is *object slicing*, which breaks programs silently.

Comment: @j_random_hacker That is why I suggested to use some kind of smart pointer. Storing objects of base type (if it has no pure functions) would cause slicing

Answer (score 0):

This was the answer (from Rubby)

```
BaseClass* Base[2];

Base[0] = new FirstDerivedClass;
Base[1] = new SecondDerivedClass;
```

Comment: This does something *very* different than what your original code was trying to do. This array is allocated on the stack, while originally it was on the heap.

Comment: Yes, I guess. Now the array is a pointer and there's pointers in the array.

Answer (score 0):

Define a pointer array , the pointer type is BaseClass. 
And assign the pointer to the derivedclass to the elements of the array.
just like:

```
BaseClass* base [2];
base[0] = new FirstDerivedClass;
base[1] = new SecondDerivedClass;
```