# Base class pointers and segmentation error

Tags: c++

The following code compiles but gives segmentation error when I run it.I am using dynamic memory 
in the main using base class pointer to derived class object and that gives error when runs.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Base {
public:
  int b;
  int b1;
  Base() : b(0), b1(0) { cout << "Base constructor" << endl; }
  virtual void Input() {
    cout << "Enter number b : ";
    cin >> b >> b1;
    // return *this;
  }
  virtual ~Base() {}
};
class Derived : public Base {
public:
  int d;
  // Constructor
  Derived() : d(0) { cout << "Derived constructor" << endl; }
  void Input() {
    Base::Input();
    cout << "Enter number d : ";
    cin >> d; //>> d1;
    // return *this;
  }
  ~Derived() {}
};

int main() {
  Base *s = new Derived[2];
  // When complexity of data members increases this line causes
  // segmentation fault
  s[1].Input(); // Here the problem

  delete[] s;
}
```

Comment: Can you do the courtesy of showing where the error happens?

Comment: `Base *s = new Derived[2]`.   Danger Will Robinson!

Comment: You cannot make an array of Derived and access that array using a pointer of Base.

Comment: if you want to have an array of pointers, you should use `new` twice.

Comment: Just because something compiles does *not* mean it's a valid C++ program.

Answer (score 6):

You cannot do this:

```
Base* s = new Derived[2];
```

`s` is basically considered as an array of `Base` instances, while there are instances of `Derived` stored inside.

You either need to create an array of pointers to `Base` and populate it with pointers to dynamically created `Derived` objects (see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13048301/580083)), or, better use a vector:

```
std::vector<std::unique_ptr<Base>> s;
s.push_back(std::make_unique<Derived>());
s.push_back(std::make_unique<Derived>());
```

Answer (score 2):

The standard says (quote from latest draft):

> [expr.delete]
>
> ... In an array delete expression, if the dynamic type of the object to be deleted differs from its static type, the behavior is undefined.

You array-delete through a pointer to base type: The behaviour of your program is undefined.

Answer (score 2):

If you will execute these statements

```
std::cout << "sizeof( Base ) = " << sizeof( Base ) << '\n';
std::cout << "sizeof( Derived ) = " << sizeof( Derived ) << '\n';
```

then you can see the following output

```
sizeof( Base ) = 16
sizeof( Derived ) = 24
```

So the sizes of the classes are different.

In this expression

```
s[1]
```

there is used the pointer arithmetic. The expression is evaluated like

```
*( s + 1 )
```

that in turn can be rewritten like

```
*reinterpret_cast<Base *>( ( char * )s + sizeof( Base ) )
```

Because the static type of the pointer `s` is `Base *`.

Thus this expression `( char * )s + sizeof( Base )` is not a pointer to the second element of the type Derived because instead of using the subexpression `sizeof( Derived )` there is used the subexpression `sizeof( Base )`.